# Определить части речи

Tags: части-речи

начато строительство

Comment: Дополнение.

Comment: @НАТАЛЬЯ, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось, либо предложите свой вариант ответа.

Comment: Я думаю, что НАЧАТО - это причастие.  
Хотела бы себя проверить.

Answer (score 1):

Начато строительство.

Начато - краткое причастие (начать - начатый - начат) в роли именной части составного именного сказуемого при пропущенной связке.

Comment: София, а какая тут связка?

Comment: Незнаменательной связкой в составном именном сказуемом является глагол "быть" (в настоящей времени он имеет нулевую форму): начато строительство - было начато строительство.